# Torrent Client with OpenVPN Connection

Tags: windows, vpn, bittorrent

I'm looking for a Torrent client that offers the ability to use an OpenVPN connection. Currently, I have to use OpenVPN to reroute my entire computer's traffic along with the Torrent client. I'd like to instead simply have the Torrent client on the OpenVPN connection and the rest of my computer network working without any proxy.

Requirements:

- Compatible with Windows 10
- Can be free or paid
- Works with OpenVPN Connections (settings either manually set or imports an .ovpn file)